# Contour lines or Contour curve?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For the plane $z=50$ on the surface $z=75-x^2-y^2$, the contour lines is the circle $x^2+y^2=25$ in the xy-plane.

My question is why we say "contour lines" not "contour curve", also we use "lines" not "line" ?

Comment: These terms are used interchangeably

Comment: if the graph of $z$ is chopped with the plane $z=50$, the resulting circle $x^2+y^2=25$ is the contour curve. It is a single curve and not a (straight) line. If the objective function $z$ is a linear function (of degree one), then there will be contour line (if cut by one plane) or contour lines (if cut by several planes).